# Laravel run artisan queue:work from inside php in background

Tags: php, laravel

We have laravel 5.6 and a lot of queues.

On production I have Supervisor that handles these queues.

On localhost I use the "sync" option to process all queues synchroniously / directly.

I wonder if it is possible to have a different behaviour on localhost:

I want to dispatch the job and then run the following command via php exec directly after that:

```
exec('php ../artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=1 --memory=768 --timeout=3600 --env=local --once &');
```

This should run the queue worker in the background once.

But nothing happens. Does artisan even work in such a scenario?

Comment: possible, make change of the relative path to absolute path. But you will have endless workers stack on background, what is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: The purpose is to execute things on localhost directly but in background. Are you sure this works? exec('php '.base_path().'/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=1 --memory=768 --timeout=3600 --env=local --once &'); does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working on windows with

```
popen( 'start C:\php\php.exe -c "C:\php\php.ini" '.base_path().'/artisan queue:work --env=local --once', 'r' );
```